# Inserting in to an Ordered Array using Binary Search

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

The following is what i have so far. The problem is how do i find the insertion spot. I did some hand tracing on paper and what i observed was eventually the lowerbound and upperbound equal and the insertion spot is always a index higher than the index of lower and upper bounds when they are equal.

I know there are many solutions online but i am really trying to understand this on my own since i only learn and remember things when i learn on my own rather than trying to figure out how others came up with a solution.

If someone can guide me it would be great. Also once i get the insertion spot i can do the rest which is moving all the values a index lower to make spot for the insertion value.

```
   public void insert(long value) {

            int lowerBound = 0;
            int upperBound = nElems - 1;
            int curIn;

            while (true) {
                curIn = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;

                if (a[curIn] < value)
                    lowerBound = curIn + 1;
                else
                    upperBound = curIn - 1;

            }
```

Comment: `while (true)` with no `break` ?

Comment: yeah was thinking of putting break after i figure out the insertion spot..

Comment: `eventually the lowerbound and upperbound equal` Why not add a check to see whether the two are equal, then, before the other checks in the loop? If you know your base case, check for it. :)

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, so if they equal am i safe to assume that the insertion spot is 1 index higher than the index where they equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary search has to check for three cases inside the loop:

1. the value searched for is smaller than the current center element
2. the value searched for is larger than the current center elelemt
3. the value is equal to the current center element (the search is finished then)

Binary search should abort, when the `lowerBound` equals the `upperBound` *and* the position in question is *not* equal to the value searched for.

Anyway, the position at which the search ends is the position where you want to insert the value: if the value at that position equals the value you want to insert, it doesn't matter if you insert at this position or after. If it is smaller, you want to insert after this position, if it is larger, you want to insert at this position.

I won't give code, as OP clearly just asked for a hint.

Comment: Yeah how do you determine the insertion spot though? because eventually your lower and upper bound range gets small enough where you are down to one index ...

Comment: Yes, this is what happens in the worst-case. At that point the value at that position could be the same as the one you want to insert, or it is different: If it is smaller, you want to insert after that position, if it is larger, you want to insert before.

Comment: So once i have lower and upper bound equal to each other, am i safe to assume that the insertion spot is either higher or lower than that?

Comment: Yes, it has to be like that because we initially defined that the array is sorted. Of course you can assume this too, when a[curIn] equals the value you want to insert. curIn is then the spot you want to put the value.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help:

```
public void insert(long value) {
    int lowerBound = 0;
    int upperBound = nElems - 1;
    int curIn;

    while (lowerBound!=upperBound) { //terminating condition - otherwise you will obtain an infinite loop.
        curIn = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;
        //take a choice: put your element immediately before a greater element.
        if (a[curIn] <= value) { //also the same value must be managed as more little than the current.
            lowerBound = curIn + 1;
        } else {
            //You cannot skip curIn lowering down the upper limit, curIn should be the position you are looking for.
            upperBound = curIn; // - 1;
        }
    }

    insert_in_list( value, curIn ); //do it as you wish. place the new element in the curIn position
}
```

Comment: This is inefficient. You may stop early when a[curIn] equals the value you want to insert.

Comment: True in general, but I did the assumption of "put your element immediatley before a greater element". This assumption orders the element with the same values based on the time of the insertion. I don't know in which application that function will be used. I don't know if the time is important or not. To simplify and to be able to provide a useful answer I did the hypothesis.